# VB.Net (WinForms) Drawing a Line to Follow the Cursor

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics, drawing

## The Problem

I am trying to have the line draw to the cursors current position as it moves. I've tried adding the code below to the **MouseMove** event in the form; however, nothing changed. I have been able to successfully draw the line, but regardless of what I do I just can't seem to get the line to follow the mouse. Also, it would be nice to be able to achieve this with reliable code without using a timer (for resources sake), but whatever works, works.

## Code

The program is simply a blank form. So far this is all I got for code (this is all of the code):

```
Public Class drawing

Public xpos = MousePosition.X
Public ypos = MousePosition.Y

Public Sub DrawLineFloat(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    ' Create pen.
    Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
    ' Create coordinates of points that define line.
    Dim x1 As Single = xpos
    Dim y1 As Single = ypos
    Dim x2 As Single = 100
    Dim y2 As Single = 100
    ' Draw line to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, x1, y1, x2, y2)
End Sub

Private Sub drawing_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    DrawLineFloat(e)
End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, I tried to modify the code for the **MouseMove** event, but it failed (I'm just including it anyways so you can see the previous attempt). Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So simply you need to draw a line from cursor position to 100,100  in a form? Is it? What doesn't work then?

Comment: It needs to follow the cursor when it moves. The line just stays stationary. @SriramSakthivel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you need:

```
private Point? startPoint;
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    if (startPoint.HasValue)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 2f))
        {
            g.DrawLine(p, startPoint.Value, new Point(100, 100));
        }
    }
}

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);

    this.startPoint = e.Location;
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

`this` refers to the `Form` instance.

Code translated to Vb.Net using http://converter.telerik.com/

```
Private startPoint As System.Nullable(Of Point)
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    If startPoint.HasValue Then
        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
        Using p As New Pen(Color.Black, 2F)
            g.DrawLine(p, startPoint.Value, New Point(100, 100))
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(e As MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)

    Me.startPoint = e.Location
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep, I will need a translator. I'm only good in VB and C++. C# is kind of right in between there.

Comment: Looks good, how should I implement this solution into my existing code? Should I call the functions within the MouseMove event?

Comment: I've never see protected overrides part before. I don't really understand those bits.

Comment: @user3357160 `Me` refers to `Form`, you've to add this code in any `Form` and that should work. You anyway need to call `Invalidate` method in form to repaint it. Is drawing class inherits Form?